# Auto font size label Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking a way to create a render for a label. I need to show some information (for example: the barcode number) I need it to fit on the label reserved space

I want to show the info with the maxim font size has posible to fit on a single line. And I need to auto resize the text if it is necesary

I read a few blogs about the auto resize of the text on Xamarin, but all of the solutions looks complicated and outdated.

I would like to ask if some one has some code or some updated idea to solve this funccionality, thank you

Comment: Unless someone made a package that  would just work, I would expect this to be complicated.

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to use `textview.SetAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(AutoSizeTextType.Uniform)` and `uilabel.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` on Android and ios.

For Android

in your custom renderer:

```
class AutoFitLabel:LabelRenderer
{
    public AutoFitLabel(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.SetAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(AutoSizeTextType.Uniform);
    }
}
```

For ios:

```
public class AutoFitLabel: LabelRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged (
        ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        var label = Control as UILabel;
        if (label != null)
        {
            label.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;             
        }
    }
}
```

and call in your forms xaml:

```
<Label HeightRequest="80" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" MaxLines="1"
               Text="This Label hasset Height to 80">
</Label>
```

Comment: Thank Leo, sorry for my delay I was on vacations. I will check it this week if it works for me

Comment: Good solution thanks. For older Android versions just use this to avoid errors TextViewCompat.SetAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(this.Control, TextViewCompat.AutoSizeTextTypeUniform);

Comment: One addition to the IOS custom renderer I had to make to get this to work was to add the following two lines:
label.BaselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustment.AlignCenters;
label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.Clip;
Hope this helps someone else somewhere along the way.